# Is there a better way to observe add and remove from an Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array which is controlled in my GUI by an NSArrayController bound to a NSTableView. The underlying array is in the ViewController.

I want to know when an new element is added or removed. I specifically want to know the element added or removed.

I tried subclassing NSArrayController to override Add / Remove - this felt the right way to go but I couldn't get it to work.

I've ended up doing the following:

```
@objc dynamic var dataArray: [ActivityGraphDefinition] = []{
    willSet{ oldArray = dataArray}
    didSet{ dataArrayChanged() }
}
```

By getting a reference to the oldArray I can then compare the two and work out what was added or removed in the dataArrayChanged() method. It works but really doesn't feel right.

Is there a better way ?  I've search online but not yet managed to find a decent method.

Comment: How are elements added or removed? Usually the best way would be to intercept the event at the source - e.g., a button click, a network response, a push notification, etc, and then do whatever you need to do at the same time.

Comment: If you have only the old and new array, you can try to run some kind of diff on them. However, if that's the case, your architecture is already too complicated. Make the array private and create methods for adding and removing, if you want to intercept them.

Comment: you're right it's too complicated... thats why it just doesn't feel right. Should be easy to do this !  The elements are added and removed via buttons in the gui that called the add / remove method on the NSArrayController

Answer (score 1):

One small improvement you could make is to change it to this:

```
@objc dynamic var dataArray: [ActivityGraphDefinition] = []{
    didSet{ dataArrayChanged(old: oldValue, new: dataArray) }
}
```

The `didSet` closure already has a parameter called `oldValue` passed in.  This at least saves you needing to implement a `willSet` and another ivar (`oldArray`) to compare old vs. new, so is a bit cleaner and more simple.

It doesn't really change your existing method of intercepting and handling the changes for the better, but if you end up keeping that approach it will at least simplify it a bit and involve less state.

Comment: that is an improvement. I really didn't like having the var for the old array. Thanks